# jQuery Ajax GET request returns 500 error in some cases

Tags: jquery, ajax

What would be the reason of receiving 500 internal server error after trying to load some pages with JS (jQuery) ajax?

Please do the console test on https://beerservice.pl/
When I try to GET:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/",
dataType: "html",
error: function(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
} });
```

or some static page:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://beerservice.pl/pl/i/Kontakt/15",
dataType: "html",
error: function(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
} });
```

everything is ok, I receive code 200 and the full HTML in response.
But when I try to GET a product page which normally works in browser, like:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://beerservice.pl/pl/p/Pegas-NovoTap-/343",
dataType: "html",
error: function(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
} });
```

then I receive 500 error. I can't see the point.
Unfortunately this is SaaS software and the developer doesn't provide the support for this.

Comment: It shouldn't be this way, your ajax query is OK. It is either a bug or some custom security measure, which detects AJAX request and blocked further requests. If you try to run this AJAX request, get 500 error and then try to open this link directly in browser, you will get 500 error again! And if you open this link again in an incognite mode, then it works well. Which suggests that it can be a security measure...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Yeldar! If this is a custom security, is there a good way to hide that we are doing AJAX request?

Comment: It depends on the implementation. The best answer is not to scrap website content, but use proper API.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a CORS problem, executing the last ajax call from my browser gives me the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://beerservice.pl/pl/p/Pegas-NovoTap-/343' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

So the page has an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that makes the request fail. Nevertheless you can use a custom proxy or one of the free proxies online that avoids that CORS restrictions.

Please take a look at the snippet below, it uses [allorigins.win](https://allorigins.win/) to proxy the request to the desired page.

There is plenty of proxies like this online for free: https://gist.github.com/jimmywarting/ac1be6ea0297c16c477e17f8fbe51347

I would recommend you to go with a custom proxy instead of trusting someone else one.

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://beerservice.pl/pl/p/Pegas-NovoTap-/343') + '&callback=?', function(data){
 alert(data.contents);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```